# Is there a measure for the space of submanifolds?

Tags: pr.probability, gt.geometric-topology, riemannian-geometry

Let $(M,\mu)$ be a pair of a manifold $M$ ($C^\infty$ or Riemann if you like) and a probability measure $\mu$ on $M$. Is there a sensible way to put a probability measure on the space of submanifolds of M, taking into account the measure $\mu$?

Comment: The space of submanifolds is not finite-dimensional, so not locally compact. This makes the question very delicate.

Comment: I was thinking about sampling n times iid. from M according to $\mu$, taking as the submanifold the union of all $\epsilon$ balls around the samples. This gives a distribution on the space of submanifolds. Letting $(n,\epsilon)$ tend towards $(\infty, 0)$ in a well behaved manner we could hope to get a a limit distribution but it seems very unclear how $n$ has to depend on $\epsilon$ and how to describe this limit distribution.

Comment: @Takirion: why is that a measure around submanifolds, but not a measure around subsets that are not very smooth? The essence of the submanifold is its smoothness, like a fine whiskey.

Comment: @BenMcKay: Every (open) ball is an open subset of $M$, as is the union of these balls $\cup B_\epsilon(X_i) = U$. Open subsets of (smooth) manifolds are (smooth) manifolds. Therefore for every finite n and positive $\epsilon$ we have that $\nu(A) = \mathbb{P}(U\in A)$ is a probability measure on the set of submanifolds. These measures might however not converge to a measure, even when letting $n$ and $\epsilon$ to to their limit simultaneously.

Comment: You should say **open** submanifolds, then

Comment: I think, the work of P. Michor can help you very much (eg https://arxiv.org/pdf/1202.3677). But there are better among his papers and books.